# i want to add parameter so that i can output will be specify output

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

when i run the report i get output display and pdf report is generated know i want to display specify report mean when i will enter employee_id =101 than that employee_id =101 should displat and pdf should generate

```
DECLARE 
rept REPORT_OBJECT; 
v_rep VARCHAR2(100); 
rep_status varchar2(200); 
vc_runformat varchar2(200);
des_format ParamList; 
BEGIN 

--des_format :=create_parameter_list('input_params');

rept := find_report_object('EMPS'); 

SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_SERVER, 'repsrv'); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_DESTYPE,FILE); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_DESFORMAT,'PDF');
--SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_MODE,'BITMAP');
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_desname,:control.filnam||to_char(sysdate,'hhmiss')||'.pdf');

--web.show_document('/reports/rwservlet/getjobid' || substr(v_rep,length('repsrv')+2) || '?server=' || 'repsrv','_blank');

--Add_Parameter(rept,report_DESNAME,'PDF');

v_rep := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(rept); 
rep_status:=REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(v_rep); 
--copy_report_object_output(v_rep, 'D:\girish\form\myreport.pdf');
WHILE rep_status in ('RUNNING','OPENING_REPORT','ENQUEUED') 
LOOP 
rep_status := report_object_status(v_rep); 
END LOOP; 
IF rep_status='FINISHED' THEN 
message('REPORT WAS CORRECTLY RUN'); 
ELSE 
message('REPORT FAILED WITH STATUS: '||rep_status); 
END IF;
--destroy_parameter_list(des_format);
END;
```

i am new to oracle form and report .
plss help me out

Answer (score 1):

create user parameter in report 
filter report query by this parameter 
pass the value of parameter in your previous code

Comment: dude i had create but error is coming if possible plsss provide code